# Python Import Error No module named _ssl on Centos without sudo privilege

Tags: python, linux, centos

I want to install Plotly on a share Centos machine so I don't have the Sudo access. All the packages on this computer are outdated so I needed to install the python3 for my local user by compiling the source code and I did it. The problem is that the pip command not working and it gives me this error:

> Could not fetch URL "some url": There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping

I succed to install the packages using the whl files but again when I try to import Plotly I got this error:

> ```
> import _ssl             # if we can't import it, let the error propagate
> ```
>
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_ssl'

I tried to recompile the python again with different configurations. I tried a suggestion to put --with-ssl to the ./configure command when try to build the python but I got unknown argument warning.
Again I tried to uncomment the bellow lines from the Modules/Setup file but I got the following error during compile step.

```
ssl _ssl.c \
-DUSE_SSL -I$(SSL)/include -I$(SSL)/include/openssl \
-L$(SSL)/lib -lssl -lcrypto
```

> ./Modules/_ssl.c:3112: error: implicit declaration of function 'X509_VERIFY_PARAM_set_hostflags'
>
> ./Modules/_ssl.c: In function 'get_verify_flags':
>
> ./Modules/_ssl.c:3410: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
>
> ./Modules/_ssl.c: In function 'set_verify_flags':
>
> ./Modules/_ssl.c:3423: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
>
> ./Modules/_ssl.c: In function 'set_host_flags':
>
> ./Modules/_ssl.c:3586: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
>
> make[3]: *** [Modules/_ssl.o] Error 1

In addition During the configuration step I got the following lines regarding the ssl

> checking whether compiling and linking against OpenSSL works... yes
>
> checking for X509_VERIFY_PARAM_set1_host in libssl... no
>
> checking for --with-ssl-default-suites... python

Can anyone help me to find a solution to install Plotly on a CentOS computer without the sudo access?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: this comment might help others as I had it just now. You basically need sudo access to install `openssl-devel` and `libssl-dev` and then re `make` and `make install`. This command might be useful :  `sudo yum install openssl-devel libssl-dev`